# Moving database from iSeries to DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, database-migration, db2-400, db2-luw

I have to move a database from DB2 for iSeries V7R2 to DB2 LUW 10.5. As far as I understand, utilities such as db2move and db2look aren't available on iSeries. So what is the best technique to achieve the goal?

Comment: Check out similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504859/move-data-from-iseries-to-db2-express#33506562

Comment: Additionally, if you have Db2-connect product you can odbc/cli/federate to i-series, and use DDL extraction and load-from-cursor etc.    But moving the DDL and data alone may be the easy part of that migration..

Comment: Have you tried running the utility from the non-iseries machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to the iSeries database from a LUW machine (via DCS gateway/DB2 Connect feature) you could run the db2look from the LUW side.

**Beware** if you run the db2look on the LUW side it still gives you DDL with all the iSeries parameters. This means e.g. if a char column on iSeries could be 255 long (as on z/OS, I don't know the specs for iSeries) the db2look will still give you a create statement for that column with 255 byte although DB2 LUW only supports 254 byte CHAR columns.

Like with the db2look via "gateway" you could declare cursors on the iSeries the same way and then load directly into the target database. You may need to convert the restrictions (like mentioned above) already in the SQL Statement for the reading cursor.

Good part on the cursor approach is that due to the point that both DB2 sides are talking directly with another there is an implicit codepage conversation which you would need to manage yourself if you try to extract the data from iSeries and reload it into LUW.

Comment: This is interesting because a `CHARACTER()` on DB2 for i can support up to 32766 characters.

Comment: On LUW it would be a VARCHAR supporting up to 32k byte